# stuck !! how to integrate the bottom line...

Tags: calculus, integration, stochastic-processes

Find the exact formula for $P(X(5)=3)$, as opposed to using a numerical approximation to $P(t)=e^{\lambda t}$

Hint ; Observe that $P(x(5)=3)= P(R_{1}+R_{2} +R_{3} > 5, R_{1} + R_{2} < 5)$ . i.e one needs to find the distribution of $R_{1} + R_{2} + R_{3}$

Let $m(i)$ be the mean of $R(i)$ . then $R(i)$ is exponentially distributed. Now

$P(R(1)+R(2)+R(3)>5, R(1)+R(2) < 5)$

$= P( 5-R(3)< R(1)+R(2) < 5 ,R(3) > 0)$

$=P((5-R(3)-R(2)) < R(1) < 5-R(2), R(2) > 0, R(3)> 0)$

Now the joint distribution of $(R(1),R(2),R(3))$ is

$f(r_{1},r_{2},r_{3}) = \frac{\exp(-(r_{1} + \frac{r_{2}}{2} + \frac{r_{3}}{3}))}{(1)(2)(3)}$ as they are independent.

So the required probability in the integration of

$f (r_{1}, r_{2},r_{3})$ over $R(1)$ varying in $(5-R(3)-R(2)) < R(1) < 5-R(2)$ and $R(2)$ and $R(3)$ lies in the entire positive real number. the integration should give the answer. how to integrate this part?